# Will PoS lover the tx fees?

Tags: gas, proof-of-stake, gas-price

There's a lot of speak about PoS being more environmentally friendly and making transactions faster to be included in the blockchain but I haven't found any info on the fees. Will the minimum gas needed (currently 2100) or the average gas price go down?

edit: I'm aware of [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7784/what-will-be-the-transaction-fee-when-ethereum-shifts-to-pos) question/answer but it is 1.5 years old when PoS was only a far future plan and so the answer is "we don't know yet" but with the casper testnet going alive recently there should be a better answer (or just a more sophisticated guess) IMO.

Comment: That question/answer is 1.5 years old when PoS was only a far future plan and so the answer is "we don't know yet" but with the casper testnet going alive recently there should be a better answer (or just a more sophisticated guess) IMO.

Comment: (As the person who answered the question mentioned as a duplicate, I haven't read anything recently that would lead me to change the answer - it's still uncertain, as far as I can tell. I think the Casper testnet is based on different economic parameters than will be used when Casper FFG goes live, so it's perhaps safest to not draw too many conclusions from it.)